# How to add multiple records into a google app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to update a datastore by uploading a formatted file(contains multiple lines). Each line in the file will create a new record in google app engine datastore. I am not sure how to add multiple rows to the datastore within a for loop. I tried:

```
class Records(db.Model): 
      something = db.StringProperty()

.....

for line in lines   #lines is a file contains multiple lines
  record = Records(parent = PARENT_KEY)  
  record.something = line
  record.put()
```

It doesn't work and the error message is BadValueError: Property something is not multi-line. I am guessing it's because the 'record' variable refer to the same instance across each iteration.

Sorry if it's a stupid question. I am pretty new to python and google app engine. Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for line in lines` will keep the newline characters at the end of the lines; newlines aren't allowed in a StringProperty unless it's designated as multiline.

try `record.something = line.rstrip()` to remove the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bulk loader to load data from a file into the datastore.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html